# How to send http requests to the kubelet api server

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I have a kubernetes cluster on EKS, in which I would like to send requests to the kubelet server (not the kube-apiserver, but the kubelet, which runs on each of the worker nodes).
My understanding is that the kubelet runs an http server on port 10250, so I opened the firewall (security group) in one of the worker nodes for that port so I can reach it from my IP. Example of a request:

`curl -k https://public-ip-of-worker-node:10250/metrics/probes`

but I get a 401 in response. I guess this is expected, as I am not authenticating in any way. 
So, how can I authenticate to the kubelet server? I can communicate without problem with the kube-apiserver using kubectl, so I do have enough permissions from the [IAM side.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managing-auth.html)

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet-authentication-authorization/) start the kubelet with the `--authentication-token-webhook` and the `--kubeconfig` flags.

Then you can create a service-account and define role and rolebinding on the service account and use the service accounts bearer token with the curl command to call the kubelet API.